# Celery send mail for every failed task

Tags: python, django, django-celery, celery-task

I am using celery in my django application and I have set-up celery flower to monitor the tasks of celery. I have setup tasks where emails are send to the user when they register/submit/FP etc events. Now Flower gives me a nice details of the task and it's status. Now for every failed task I wanted an email to send to my account so that I don't have check the flower everyday for the failed task. **I did the following configuration in my settings.py file**

```
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
```

and `ADMINS`.

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'noreply@xyz.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xyz123@'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST = 'xyz.abc.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

These are settings of "From" email address. 
Few days back,one of my team member accidentally changed the password of the above email_host and forgot to update settings file. **It wasn't after it was too later that the tasks are failing because of SMTP Authentication error.**

Is there any way around this that even if SMTP authentication error occurs, I immediately get the email from celery ? I am not so sure about this.

Are there any other tools that will monitor my tasks and for every failed task it will send me the mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that there is a table created for maintaining the tasks in the database. So I just simply created a script which will check for failed task every hour for the past hour records in the table and if found any it will send an email.

**script.py**

```
#!venv/bin/python2

import os
from django.conf import settings

if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    os.sys.path.append(
        os.path.dirname(
            os.path.dirname(
                os.path.abspath(__file__))))

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "rest_apis.settings")

import django

django.setup()
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from djcelery.models import TaskMeta
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time


USERS_TO_NOTIFY = ['ops@yopmail.com']
TIME_THRESHOLD_INTERVAL = 60

def send_email(email_subject_line, email_body):
    email = EmailMessage(email_subject_line,
                         email_body,
                         settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                         USERS_TO_NOTIFY
                         )
    email.send()


def main():
    current_time = datetime.now()   # Get Current TimeStamp
    time_threshold = current_time - timedelta(minutes=TIME_THRESHOLD_INTERVAL) # Get 60 minutes past current time stamp
    celery_taskmeta_objects = TaskMeta.objects.filter(status="FAILURE", date_done__gte=time_threshold)

    email_body = "Below are the tasks which failed : "
    if celery_taskmeta_objects.exists():
        for celery_taskmeta in celery_taskmeta_objects:
            print celery_taskmeta.task_id
            email_body += "\n\ntask_id : %s" % celery_taskmeta.task_id
            email_body += "\nstatus : %s" % celery_taskmeta.status
            email_body += "\ndate : %s" % celery_taskmeta.date_done
            email_body += "\ntraceback :"
            email_body += "\n%s\n\n" % celery_taskmeta.traceback
        email_subject_line = '[URGENT] Celery task failure in last %s minutes' % (TIME_THRESHOLD_INTERVAL)
        send_email(email_subject_line, email_body)


main()
```

Now in an email I get a full stack trace too and the id of the task. Now my requirement was to check every hour so I just put the script in a crontab. Now you can change the time threshold as per your basic need and work accordingly.

Comment: Is an email with the traceback being sent repeatedly?

Answer (score -2):

You can configure Datadog https://www.datadoghq.com/

It can monitor and track your dynamic infrastructure. You would receive an email for every error occurred on your production server.